# R - Econometria - Teste Wald e autocorrelação

Tags: r, testes

Boa tarde,

Gostaria de saber como realizar o Teste Wald (para heterocedasticidade) e o teste proposto por Wooldridge para autocorrelação.

Estou usando dados em painel (não-balanceado), com Pooled OLS, Efeitos Fixos e Efeitos Aleatórios com a library(plm).

Alguém saberia me dizer?

Answer (score 3):

Percebi que sua pergunta procura testes bem específicos,
caso te ajude.
eu uso para autocorrelação
**durbin watson**

```
    DW<-dwtest(lm(Y~X))
```

Heterocedasticidade.
**goldfeld quandt**

```
   GQ2<-gqtest(lm(Y~X))
```

Até então só os conheço na função lm e não obtive sucesso usando em auto-regressores.

Comment: obrigado ! Vou pesquisar.